# Exercise on radius of convergence of power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, power-series

I have solved the following exercise and I would like to know if I have made any mistakes:

Let $\sum a_n x^n$ be a power series with $a_n\neq 0$ and assume $L=|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ exists.

(a) Show that if $L\neq 0$ then the series converges for all $x\in (-\frac{1}{L},\frac{1}{L})$.

(b) Show that if $L\neq 0$ then the series converges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

(c) Show that (a) and (b) continue to hold if $L$ is replaced by the limit $L':=\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n$, where $s_n=\sup\{|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}|:k\geq n\}$

My solution:

(a) By Ratio Test with $b_{n}:=a_{n}x^n$ (note we can assume $x\neq 0$ since for $x=0$ the power series is obviously convergent): $|\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_n x^n}|=|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}x|=|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}||x|\xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty} L|x|<1\Leftrightarrow |x|<\frac{1}{L}$ i.e. $x\in (-\frac{1}{L},\frac{1}{L})$.

(b) It follows from the same reasoning used in (a): with $|\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_n x^n}|=|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}x|=|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}||x|\xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty} 0<1$ so the series is convergent at $x$.

(c) By a generalization of the Ratio Test we know that if $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\{|\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}|:k\geq n\} <1 $ then the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ converges. If we use this test with $b_n=a_n x^n$ we have that the power series converges at $x$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\{|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}||x|:k\geq n\}=|x|\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\{|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}||x|:k\geq n\}=|x|\cdot L'<1$ i.e. if $|x|<\frac{1}{L'}$ or, equivalently, if $x\in (-\frac{1}{L'}, \frac{1}{L'})$, as desired for (a). For (b), by the same process we get that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\{|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}||x|:k\geq n\}=|x|\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\{|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}||x|:k\geq n\}=|x|\cdot L'=|x|\cdot 0=0<1$ for every $x$, as desired.

Comment: $$|\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_nx^n}|=|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}x|$$ a typo.

Comment: @macton $|\frac{a_{n+1}x}{a_n}|=|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}||x|$

Comment: yes, but you write $|\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_n}x^n|=|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}x|$, which made no sense.

Comment: @macton ah, I was looking only at part (c), sorry: thank you for pointing that out, I have upvoted your comments.

Comment: @macton: I was working today on the same problem. Would it also be valid if I said that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right\rvert < L'$, because the supremum of $ \left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right\rvert$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is $L'$? And, as a result, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1} x^{n+1}}{a_{n} x^{n}} \right\rvert < L'\lvert x \rvert$. Giving us the desired result (using the same technique as in your answer).